# run jawr with spring-boot

Tags: spring-boot, jawr

I'm trying to integrate jawr into my spring-boot project, I add jawr.properties under resources folder and jawr dependence but it seems that spring boot does not read my config file ! am I missing something ? please help me guys.
Thx

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to put the properties of the jawr.properties file into the application.properties?

Comment: Please change this into a comment

Comment: @Marged sorry i can't, don't have the reputation